# locality-aware Mergesort

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting

Let `A` be an array with a total order to be sorted. We say `A` has locality `d` iff each element is at most `d` indices away from its final index in the sorted array. In the locality-aware mergesort, instead of merging the two subarrays entirely, we only need to consider the middle `2d` elements (rightmost `d` elements in the left subarray and leftmost `d` elements in the right subarray), since other elements must be in their final position. The question is how to show that the asymptotic time performance for the locality-aware mergesort is `n log d`.

There are locality-aware versions for other sorting algorithms; the performance for the locality-aware mergesort is the only one that I don't understand.

Comment: Wouldn't this fit better at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me! Nice question though

Answer (score 1):

Well it makes sense. if you think about it: merge sort is O(nlog n), for each element (n elements) it would take a maximum of log n iterations for it to be in its place in the array (the maximum distance an item can "travel" is n). For your example it would only be log d be because the distance the item can travel is capped at d. at least that is how I see it.